# Variation of the Kakeya Needle Problem with positive thickness

Tags: reference-request, optimization, area, kakeya-sets

> What  is  the  least  area  in  the  plane  required  to  continuously  rotate  a  needle  of  unit  length  and
>   **positive** thickness $a \in ]0,1[$ around completely (i.e. $360°$)?

The answer is known to be $0$ (we take the infimum) if $a=0$.
An obvious and very rough upper bound is $\pi  (\sqrt{1+a^2}/2)^2 = \pi(1+a^2)/4$.
I've found nothing on this version of Kakeya Needle Problem. If you have any reference on this version, it would be welcome.

Comment: I remember seeing an amazing paper here about this problem and the Riemann hypothesis...

Comment: @anomaly: something like this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137805/riemann-hypothesis-and-kakeya-needle-problem or http://www.one-zero.eu/resources/Kakeya.pdf "Riemann and Mobius dust the Kakeya Problem"?

Comment: @anomaly:Apparently someone just asked on MO: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pQCNRi62smsJ:mathoverflow.net/questions/247988/the-riemann-hypothesis-proof-and-the-kakeya-needle-problem+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=ch&client=safari But this is completely unrelated to my question.

Comment: if you take the needle moving as the chord of a circle of radius $r$, the area is $\pi r^2 - \pi (r-f(r)-a)^2 \approx 2 \pi r (f(r)+a)$ where $f(r) = r (1-\cos(\arcsin(1/2r))) \approx r(1-\cos(1/2r)) \approx \frac{1}{8r}$

Comment: It is, in fact, totally unrelated. :) That person pops up here (and on mathoverflow, and various other boards) every couple of weeks with the identical post and paper.

Comment: So I think that's how it $\to 0$ when $a \to 0$, but for a fixed $a$ the optimum is rotating it without moving the center (weird ?)